# Custom Felix command with iPOJO annotations

Tags: annotations, osgi, apache-felix

I'm currently trying to implement a custom shell command for Felix using iPOJO. My sample implementation looks like:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Provides;
import org.apache.felix.shell.Command;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Provides
public class SampleCommand implements Command {


    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "testcmd";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return "testcmd";
    }

    @Override
    public String getShortDescription() {
        return "test command";
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(String line, PrintStream out, PrintStream err) {
        out.println("execute testcmd!");
    }

}
```

When I deploy the Bundle on Felix, my SampleCommand gets instantiated and the getName() gets called. But when I try to execute "testcmd" on the shell, I get:

```
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: testcmd
```

Are there any further points I need to consider?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the feedback given above by user1231484 and earcam, here a minimal working example:

```
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Provides;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.ServiceProperty;
import org.apache.felix.service.command.Descriptor;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Instantiate
@Provides(specifications = ListComponentsCommand.class)
public class ListComponentsCommand {

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.scope", value = "test")
    String scope;

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = "{}")
    String[] function = new String[] { "test" };

    @Descriptor("test")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test!");
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, you should have enough points to accept your own answer =)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you need to subclass Command anymore ([this page](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-shell.html#ApacheFelixShell-creating) looks very old), I think it should work just be registering a service with two specific properties:

1. The scope "osgi.command.scope" property (which essentially provides a namespace in case your command names are the same as those provided by another.
2. A string array "osgi.command.function" with the names of your methods acting as commands

This way your commands don't need to know anything about OSGi.  You use print streams in the usual way (these are redirected by the shell)

E.g.

```
@ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.scope", value = "mycommands")
@ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = {"execute", "add"})
@Component(immediate = true)
@Provides
public class SampleCommand implements MyOwnCommand {

    @Override
    public void execute(String line) {
        System.out.println("execute testcmd! with line: " + line);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a + "+" + b + "=" + (a+b));
    }

}
```

The only price you pay for this is losing the help and usage functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I cannot set the @Property annotation for classes (compiler error "disallowed for this location"). Is there anything I might have misunderstood?

Comment: @earcam The annotations were correct so far, the only problem was, that `@ServiceProperty` needed to be placed at field level. Thanks anyway, good pointer :)

Answer (score 2):

You're developing a command for the Felix Shell (old). However, since quite some time Felix now uses Gogo (implementing an OSGi standard). So you should check http://felix.apache.org/site/rfc-147-overview.html to provide a new command.

Moreover you can have a look to [the iPOJO Arch command for Gogo](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.ipojo.arch.gogo/1.0.1/org/apache/felix/ipojo/arch/gogo/Arch.java). It's using iPOJO itself.

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled over the Arch code snipped yesterday night, which actually helped me to come up with a working version now.